# Menu sliding out from left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help.

Navigate to this website: http://www.webeffectual.com/

You can see the three white lines on the top left corner of the website. When you hover those lines, there are three boxes that are sliding out from the left. And when you hover those boxes a text appears. That is what I don't know how to accomplish.

Here is my code so far:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Index.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="Menu">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The code is just a empty html. :(
And my css is also empty

If you know how to do this, please write a comment or send a link to a website that explains how to to this. It would be highly appreciated.

Srry if im explaining it so bad. I am from sweden and i dont know so much english:3

Comment: The code you can suss out by looking at the css and the jQuery used on that site. The hamburger (the three lines) is on .hover and .click and (jQuery) is used to toggleClass. At first it's off canvas using css positioning and the when clicked the class it toggles to changes the positioning with CSS. You can google side push menu, slide in menu from left, and various other search strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually achieve this with very little javascript. The menu itself has a `fixed` position and is off canvas. When the 'hamburger menu' (the three lines) is hovered over, a displayed class is added to menu, sliding it to the left onto the canvas using `transform: translateX`.

Here's a CodePen example: http://codepen.io/bwalker8038/pen/MYWXdx

Comment: I tried to copy and paste the codes into dreamweaver but its not working :( @brad

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" >

    <!-- Custom styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css">
   <!--[if lt IE 10]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie9-and-down.css" />
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie9-and-down.css" />
  <![endif]-->

   <!-- Web fonts -->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' 

   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-   
  awesome.css"    rel="stylesheet">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com
  /css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500|Montserrat:400,700">

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="ico/apple-touch-  
    icon-144-precomposed.jpg">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="ico/apple-touch-
    icon-114-precomposed.jpg">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="ico/apple-touch- 
    icon-72-precomposed.jpg">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="ico/apple-touch-icon-57-
   precomposed.jpg">
                               <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png">


     <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

     </head>


   <body class="home portfolio">


   <div id="wrapper">

   <header>
   <div class="side-nav">
      <ul class="gn-menu-main" id="gn-menu">
        <li class="gn-trigger">
          <a class="gn-icon gn-icon-menu"><span>Menu</span></a>
          <nav class="gn-menu-wrapper">
            <div class="gn-scroller">
              <ul class="gn-menu" id="main-nav">
                <li class="current"><a href="#intro"><span><img src="img/home-
   icon.png"></span>Home</a></li>
                 <li class="about"><a href="#whatwedo"><span><img src="img/about-
    icon.png"></span>About</a></li>
                <li class="work"><a href="#features"><span><img src="img/work-
       icon.png"></span>Projects</a></li>
                <li class="contact"><a href="#contact"><span><img src="img/contact-
    icon.png"></span>Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /gn-scroller -->
          </nav>
        </li>

        <!-- logo -->
        <li class="logo-wrapper"><a href="#" class="logo home"><img src="img/logo.png">
       </a></li>

      </ul>
       </div>

     </header>


      <!-- Intro Section -->
     <section class="section current" id="intro">
     <div class="intro-wrapper">
     <div class="right slideRight"><img src="img/flowers.png"><img class="fade-in one 
   b-flowers" src="img/brought-flowers.png"></div>

    <div class="left">
        <h1>Digital success isn't a one night stand.<span>Relationships matter.  
   </span></h1>           
        <div id="ticker"><h3>Soooo, how about a date?</h3></div>
       <div class="fade-in two"><a href="#features" class="btn cta scrollAnchor">Our 
     Work<span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-angle-down"></span></a></div></div>
     </div> <!-- end Wrapper -->

       <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
     <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
   < ![endif]-->
  <!--[if (gte IE 9) | (!IE)]><!-->
   <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--<![endif]-->

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">     
  </script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.collagePlus.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.removeWhitespace.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.caroufredsel.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
   <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.gnmenu.js"></script>
   <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/counter.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jticker.js"></script>
   <script>
    jQuery(document).delay(2000).queue(function(){
   jQuery("#ticker").addClass( "visible" ).ticker({
    cursorList:  "|",
    rate:        130
    }).trigger("play").trigger("stop");
    });
     </script>
    <!-- LESS SCRIPT (RECOMMENDED IF YOU KNOW LESS CSS) -->
   <script src="js/less-1.3.3.min.js"></script>

   <!-- PRELOADER -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // &lt;![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function() { $(".preloader").fadeOut("fast"); })
     // ]  ]&gt;

    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20100120-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

     (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = 
        true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
   'http://www')    
  +        '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
       ,,,,   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];     
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
   })();

  </script>




  </body></html>
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Why is there so much code, what does it all do? Try to minimise the code to just the part where you fixed the problem, and add some explanation as to what you did.